# Is there any way to schedule non hadoop jobs in Talend

Tags: scheduler, talend

Can anyone suggest some method to schedule non hadoop jobs in Talend OpenStudio for Big Data.
I have seen a scheduler using oozie, but it will work for hadoop related jobs only.

Comment: Using a plugin I'm currently testing you could be able to schedule talend jobs using SOS Job Scheduler. Give me a day of two to bake a good article about it and I'll answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export your job as a JAR and then use your system's scheduler to run the JAR as normal.

To do this on Windows you should schedule the java.exe with an argument of your exported job JAR location.